# Calling size in Matlab user function causes error

Tags: function, matlab

This should be a simple question for Matlab users out there.

The parameter y is 1 x 81 matrix (an array).
My function looks like this:

```
function [  ] = test( y )

length(y)

end
```

Yet when call test I get the following error: 
"??? Attempt to reference field of non-structure array."
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a return parameter!

```
function [size] = test (y ) etc...
```

Comment: @Casbar77 wonderful! and as picky as it may seem, do keep in mind AGS's comment related to namespace collisions for when your code gets very complex. While in *most* cases your code will take precedence and you won't see any issues, there are some nitpicky cases where the collision might cause issues ( i've spent hours debugging those :/ )

Answer (score -2):

`test` is a built in function, already.

```
>> help test
 --- help for classregtree/test ---

 test Compute error rate for tree.
 COST = test(T,'resubstitution') computes the cost of the tree T
```

where `T` is a decision tree.

Comment: Actually, test is a function from an added toolbox so there are no namespace collisions if he's calling test from the current path :) - i have written hundreds of test() functions haha

Comment: -1: While there maybe an already existing function with the same name in another toolbox, you _can_ use duplicate names for functions. The official documentation states that _"if you duplicate function names, MATLAB executes the one that occurs first in the search path"_.